# pid 専用のディレクトリについて

Tags: centos

・[/var/run 直下に作成したディレクトリが削除されないようにする](http://server.etutsplus.com/centos-7-tmpfiles-d-deleted-outdate-files/)というページを見て疑問に思ったのですが、CentOS7では、pid 専用のディレクトリはどこに配置すべきものですか？

・案1.任意のディレクトリ
・案2./var/run 直下
・案3.その他

・削除されない設定を書いてまで、pid 専用のディレクトリを/var/run 直下に配置した方が良い理由はありますか？？　単なる慣習？？

---

**環境**
・CentOS7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> CentOS7では、pid 専用のディレクトリはどこに配置すべきものですか？

Linuxの標準に従うのであれば、`/var/run`(または `/run`)に配置したほうが良いと思います。

> 削除されない設定を書いてまで、pid 専用のディレクトリを/var/run 直下に配置した方が良い理由はありますか？？　単なる慣習？？

[Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)というUnix系OSのディレクトリ階層標準で`/var/run`は`最近のブート以降の走行中(runing)システムに関する情報`を格納すると規定されているためだと思います。(ただし、FHS3.0 では /var/run は /run に置き換えられるそうです。)

Comment: CentOS7だと`/var/run`は`/run`へのシンボリックリンクになっていますね。

Answer (score 1):

「**そのPIDを誰が参照するのか**」によっても対応が異なると思います。

単に自分が作成したアプリケーションの二重起動を防ぐ程度なら、お行儀の良し悪しは置いておいて、自分で決めた任意のディレクトリ(例えば`/opt/AppName/var/run/`配下)でもいいでしょう。

他のサービスと依存関係があるような場合には、一般的に配布されているアプリケーションは`/var/run`配下にPIDが作成されていることを想定しているはずなので、なるべく標準に従うべきです。

`tmpfiles.d`の仕組みが必要になるのは`/var/run`の下に**サブディレクトリを作成した場合**です。
まずは`/var/run/DAEMON.pid`のように**ディレクトリ直下**にPIDファイルを作成することを検討してください。